# Passport/API access when not logged in?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

As suggested in the docs:

> Passport includes an authentication guard that will validate access tokens on incoming requests. Once you have configured the api guard to use the passport driver, you only need to specify the auth:api middleware on any routes that require a valid access token:

So I have updated my route service provider:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('auth:api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

The issue is that I can now only access my api if I am logged in, but how can it be accessed via non logged in users?

### EDIT

Please note, I do not want to create a publically accessible api from any client, only my website should be able to access it, either as a logged in or non logged in user.

Comment: This will be rather hard since any non logged in user could probably replay the requests that your frontend will send to your backend. You could "obfuscate" these request by signing the url for example but this will be temporary protection since anybody would probably be able to deduct your signing since you need to have the information to get the requests in your frontend.

Comment: But isnt this the entire point of passport, being able to consume your own api - why should the user be required to log in?

Comment: A use of passport (but by far not all uses) is protecting your api, it does this by using keys generated for the user. since there might be a not-logged-in user it will not have a key and thus not be able to use your api

Comment: But say I have an api route that lists news posts in json, how can I make it so only my client can read it (with or without a user being logged in). Seems silly that any other site could just scrape my api feed.

Answer (score 1):

While in your `routes/api.php` (or any other route file for that matter) you can use middleware groups.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() {
  Route::get('/profile' ...);
}
```

This will protect only the routes in your route group with the given middleware. All the routes outside of this group will still be accessible by non-autorized users.

This method will leave all the "unprotected" routes available to everyone on the internet. If you do not wish this you will need to protect the other routes using some other methods i.e. sending a key or token.

**Update:**
I do not know of any secure standard for your question but do have an idea. No security garanties are given or should be implied!

The best way I could think of would be creating a short lived session key. I.e. when a user first lands on your page generate and secure a crypto secure key. Store this key in the database with a timestamp of when it was generated and when it has been last used. When the user uses its key update the last used timestamp. throw an unauthenticated error if the key is generated a long time ego (1 hour for example) or the last used time is too long (10 minutes for example).
This means somebody who wants access to the api from another source than your site will only be able to for 1 hour tops.

**Update 2:**
There is another probably better option: CORS.
CORS can limit access to your resource by limiting who can access the resource. CORS can be implemented by for example [Spatie's laravel-cors package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors). In its `cors.php` config file you could update the `'allow_origins'` key to only include your own domain.

Comment: Yes, but then any client will be able to access the api. I only want my client (my website) to access the api.

Comment: Hmm I think CORS would work fine for my web app, but when I do a mobile app, that won't be able to access the API, it's like I want to authorises particular clients access.